# Get managed metadata column value in sharepoint search result using search js with keyword query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, managed-metadata, search-api

I have retrieve SharePoint search results using javascript on SharePoint Online with following code:

```
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText("queryText here");
    keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);    
    keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);    
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
```

I got results successfully in `onQuerySuccess`:

```
function onQuerySuccess() {
    $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {

        console.log(this.Title + ' - ' + this.Author);

        // I want managed metadata column value here (same as Title & Author) if managed metadata column is exist in the search result

    });    
}
```

I got Title, Author, Path properties.

Now I want to get **value of column type Managed Metadata** if that column is exist in the search result. How can I get it ? No any managed metadata column is fixed. It can be different for all search results or column should not exist in the search result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, find the solution. I have added a property `owsmetadatafacetinfo` to keyword query:

```
var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
properties.add('owsmetadatafacetinfo');
```

Then in the query `results`, I got the `null` if managed metadata column does not exist for search result.

If metadata column exist then, I got it with column & it's value for current search result with property `owsmetadatafacetinfo` :

```
function onQuerySuccess() {
    $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {

        console.log(this.Title + ' - ' + this.Author);

        /* Following will return value like:
           > Carx0020Filter|Car Filter|kpEc4Tt0Bk6aYzIoWUkAng==|YS6tyhuAgUWauGGOBUO7Hg==|#d317325c-2705-4006-8158-eea6f2629618|Lamborghini;#"             
           Here, 'Car Filter' is managed metadata column & 'Lamborghini' is value for current search result */

          console.log(this.owsmetadatafacetinfo);

    });    
}
```

It's return like:

```
Carx0020Filter|Car Filter|kpEc4Tt0Bk6aYzIoWUkAng==|YS6tyhuAgUWauGGOBUO7Hg==|#d317325c-2705-4006-8158-eea6f2629618|Lamborghini;#"
```

Where, `Car Filter` is managed metadata column (with internal name `Carx0020Filter`) & `Lamborghini` is value for current search result.

Answer (score 2):

You can get that field value, by specifying managed property name of the same field. See below snippet to add more in `get_selectProperties`.

```
// Set Properties
var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
properties.add('Size'); 
properties.add('CustomManagedProperty'); // Size, CustomManagedProperty is my custom fields which I want in results. You can specify yours.
```

Below is the example to get any additional field in Keyword query with JavaScript:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
keywordQuery.set_queryText("Search Query");

// Set Properties
var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
properties.add('Size');
properties.add('CustomManagedProperty'); // Specify your field here.

var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my requirement is that those column names (Size, CustomManagedProperty) are not fixed. There should be any metadata column whose value I have to get.

Comment: Hey Ronak, If those properties are not fixed then how would you identify the variable name (correct managed property name of the field)? Though you can give a try to add Searchable option to managed property field and verify if the result is appearing. for more info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyword-queries-and-search-conditions-for-Content-Search-c4639c2e-7223-4302-8e0d-b6e10f1c3be3#siteproperties